# How to put a quote at beginning and end of an RDD data type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking to put quotes around what is in a RDD data type. So, I have a text file and it’s loaded up into a RDD.  Here is the Scala code:

```
val file: String = "file:///data/book/starwars"
val bookStarWarsRDD = sc.textFile(file);
```

The text file is really just plan text of a star wars story, like ***Return of the Jedi***.  I am looking to place a quote on the very first word and the very last word, like:

```
"A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...
```

Then, at the very end place a quote on the last word (or the very end of the story), like:

```
...and the saga continues. The end.”
```

How can I do this with a RDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For RDD use:**

```
  val myDF = Seq(("Sentence1 something. Sentence2 something")).toDF("text")

  // You may have to adjust index of text column by replacing x(0) with x(index in ur case)
  val test = myDF.rdd.map{ case  (x) => (x(0) , "\"" + x(0) + "\"") } 
  test.foreach(println)
```

prints:

```
(Sentence1 something. Sentence2 something,"Sentence1 something. Sentence2 something")
```

**If you can use dataframe:**

```
val myDF = Seq(("Sentence1 something. Sentence2 something")).toDF("text")

val withQuotes = myDF.withColumn("textWithQuotes",concat(lit("\""),col("text"),lit("\""))  )
withQuotes.show(false)
scala> withQuotes.show(false)
+----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|text                                    |textWithQuotes                            |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|Sentence1 something. Sentence2 something|"Sentence1 something. Sentence2 something"|
+----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I use this with a RDD?

Comment: @SteveMcAffer: Edited for RDD

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `wholeTextFiles` for the requirement you have as `wholeTextFiles` will read a file as a `Tuple2(filename, whole_texts)`. So you can add `"` at the beginning and end of `whole_texts`.

```
val file : String = "file:///data/book/starwars"
val bookStarWarsRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles(file).map(kv => "\""+kv._2+"\"").flatMap(_.split("\n"));
bookStarWarsRDD.foreach(println)
```

You should have your desired output.