# How to surround quotes of text in a RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD with lines of text in it.  The text is from a text file and it has new linefeeds (returns).  I am looking to place quotes on the first word and the last word in the RDD.

```
val fileRdd = sc.textFile("file://data/sample.txt")
val newRdd = fileRdd
```

Sample input from the text file.  Note that the text file has new lines or returns in it:

```
 I once did an interview for the Banbury Herald. I must look it out one of these days, for the biography. 

Strange chap they sent me. A boy, really. As tall as a man, but with the puppy fat of youth. 

It was nightfall now and I must go home.
```

Expected output in the RDD:

```
“I once did an interview for the Banbury Herald. I must look it out one of these days, for the biography. 

Strange chap they sent me. A boy, really. As tall as a man, but with the puppy fat of youth. 

It was nightfall now and I must go home.”
```

What I am looking for is putting the quotes on the first and last words and storing this in a new RDD data type. Can you help me with this?

Comment: didn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472802/5880706) helped you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, if there is no shuffle upstream, but it doesn't make any sense. If you find yourself thinking about order, beginning, end and similar concepts, you're in a sequential mindset, which doesn't fit Spark at all.

That being said:

```
val fileRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  "I once did an interview for the Banbury Herald. I must look it out one of these days, for the biography.",
  "Strange chap they sent me. A boy, really. As tall as a man, but with the puppy fat of youth.",
   "It was nightfall now and I must go home."
))
```

Find count:

```
val n = fileRdd.count
```

`zipWithIndex` and `map`:

```
val withQuotes = fileRdd.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (line, 0) => "\"" + line
  case (line, m) if m == n - 1 => line + "\""
  case (line, _) => line
}
```